# in c9 shell how can I type "<" and it'll auto-complete "<% %>"

Tags: shell, ruby-on-rails-5

How in the c9 shell can i make a function so I can type "<"[tab] then it'll auto-complete "<% %>".

I would also like to be able to type "=" and auto-complete "<%= %>".

Answer (score 0):

Here's a broad overview of how you can achieve this:

Cloud9 has keybindings and even allows you to create [custom keybindings](https://docs.c9.io/docs/customizing-keybindings). You can choose a keyboard mode in

- default
- vim
- emacs
- sublime ([example1](https://github.com/eddorre/SublimeERB#add-keybinding), [example2](https://github.com/matthewrobertson/ERB-Sublime-Snippets))

This means you should choose one of these modes to explore further and research how to create keybindings in. You may then edit keybindings in cloud9's frontend chart (preferences gear icon > keybindings) or manually in the keymap file (more detailed instructions at previous link and [here](https://docs.c9.io/v1.0/docs/keybindings)).

Comment: I dont understand how to install example 1 in c9,

Comment: @mattnapper sorry, those two are more examples of what you can achieve with sublime, but not necessarily installable in c9. But, you can look at the code in the repositories to see how they work, and apply the core parts to your keymappings